# R - Given a matrix and a power, produce multiple matrices containing all combinations of matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

Given a matrix `mat` (of size `N` by `M`) and a power, `p` (e.g., 4), produce `p` matrices, where each `p`-th matrix contains all possible combinations of the columns in `mat` at that degree.

In my current approach, I generate the `p`-th matrix and then use it in the next call to produce the `p+1`th matrix.  Can this be 'automated' for a given power `p`, rather than done manually?

I am a novice when it comes to R and understand that there is likely a more efficient and elegant way to achieve this solution than the following attempt...

```
N = 5
M = 3
p = 4
mat = matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)
mat_1 = mat
mat_2 = t(sapply(1:N, function(i) tcrossprod(mat_1[i, ], mat[i, ])))
mat_3 = t(sapply(1:N, function(i) tcrossprod(mat_2[i, ], mat[i, ])))
mat_4 = t(sapply(1:N, function(i) tcrossprod(mat_3[i, ], mat[i, ])))
```

Can anyone provide some suggestions?  My goal is to create a function for a given matrix `mat` and power `p` that outputs the `p` different matrices in a more 'automated' fashion.

Related question that got me started: [How to multiply columns of two matrix with all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446749/how-to-multiply-columns-of-two-matrix-with-all-combinations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
N = 5
M = 3
p = 4
mat = matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)

res_mat <- list()
res_mat[[1]] <- mat
for(i in 2:p) {
     res_mat[[i]] <- t(sapply(1:N, function(j) tcrossprod(res_mat[[i-1]][j, ], res_mat[[1]][j, ])))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solves your problem.

```
N = 5
M = 3
p = 4
mat = matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)
f=function(x) matrix(apply(x,2,"*",mat),nrow(x))
rev(Reduce(function(f,x)f(x), rep(c(f), p-1), mat, T,T))
```

Comment: thank you and nice work! For `N = 15000`, `M=3` and `p=4` this is on average ~200 milliseconds faster than @Aleh's solution

Comment: can this result be generalized to only produce unique columns at a given order `p`?  

E.g., for `N=5`,`M=4`, `p=2`, we get the product of columns (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3).  I want to reduce the code to only calculate products between columns (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3).  But I would want to do this for each `p`-th order.