# R - Given a matrix and a power, produce multiple matrices containing all unique combinations of matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, cross-product

Based on my related question linked below (see @Aleh solution):  I am looking to calculate only unique products between columns in a matrix for a given power.

E.g., for N=5,M=3, p=2, we get the product of columns (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3). I want to modify (@Aleh's) code to only calculate products between columns (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3). But I would want to do this for each p-th order.

Can someone help me accomplish this in R?

Many thanks in advance!

Related questions question: [R - Given a matrix and a power, produce multiple matrices containing all combinations of matrix columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916042/r-given-a-matrix-and-a-power-produce-multiple-matrices-containing-all-combina/48917169?noredirect=1#comment86084078_48917169)

Comment: If `M=4` and `p=2` you would expect 16 columns correct?

Comment: @MikeH. you noticed an error!  For my example above I meant `M=3`.  It has been corrected.  When `M=4` and `p=2`, the original 16 columns should be reduced to only 10 unique columns [(1,1,), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,3), (3,4), (4,4)].

Comment: @MikeH. the original 16 columns that would need to be reduced to the 10 unique columns given above are: [(1,1,), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), ((4,4)]

Comment: Can you quantify your efficiency requirements? What are actual values for M, N and p?

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! @RalfStubner `M` will usually be under 25 while `N` can be 5000-10,000.  `p` will usually be no larger than 3 but will be 4 at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this is what you are looking for:

```
# all combinations of p elements out of M with repetiton 
# c.f. http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html
comb_rep <- function(p, M) {
  combn(M + p - 1, p) - 0:(p - 1)
}

# use cols from mat to form a new matrix
# take row products
col_prod <- function(cols, mat) {
  apply(mat[ ,cols], 1, prod)
}

N <- 5
M <- 3
p <- 3
mat <- matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)

col_comb <- lapply(2:p, comb_rep, M)
col_comb
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
#> [2,]    1    2    3    2    3    3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
#> [2,]    1    1    1    2    2    3    2    2    3     3
#> [3,]    1    2    3    2    3    3    2    3    3     3

# prepend original matrix
res_mat <- list()
res_mat[[1]] <- mat
c(res_mat, 
  lapply(col_comb, function(cols) apply(cols, 2, col_prod, mat)))
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    6   11
#> [2,]    2    7   12
#> [3,]    3    8   13
#> [4,]    4    9   14
#> [5,]    5   10   15
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   36   66  121
#> [2,]    4   14   24   49   84  144
#> [3,]    9   24   39   64  104  169
#> [4,]   16   36   56   81  126  196
#> [5,]   25   50   75  100  150  225
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   36   66  121  216  396  726  1331
#> [2,]    8   28   48   98  168  288  343  588 1008  1728
#> [3,]   27   72  117  192  312  507  512  832 1352  2197
#> [4,]   64  144  224  324  504  784  729 1134 1764  2744
#> [5,]  125  250  375  500  750 1125 1000 1500 2250  3375
```

It is not really efficient, though, since e.g. the third power is calculated from three columns of the original matrix instead of one column of the original matrix and one column of the second power.

**Edit:** testing with realistic sizes mentioned in the comments shows that @Moody_Mudskipper's approach for the multiplication is *much* faster, while my approach for the combinations is a bit faster. So it makes sense to combine the two:

```
# original function from @Moody_Mudskipper's answer
fun <- function(mat,p) {
  mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
  combs <- do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(seq(ncol(mat))),p)) # all combinations including permutations of same values
  combs <- combs[!apply(combs,1,is.unsorted),]              # "unique" permutations only
  rownames(combs) <- apply(combs,1,paste,collapse="-")      # Just for display of output, we keep info of combinations in rownames
  combs <- combs[order(rownames(combs)),]                   # sort to have desired column order on output
  apply(combs,1,function(x) Reduce(`*`,mat[,x]))            # multiply the relevant columns
}
combined <- function(mat, p) {
  mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
  combs <- combn(ncol(mat) + p - 1, p) - 0:(p - 1)          # all combinations with repetition
  colnames(combs) <- apply(combs, 2, paste, collapse = "-") # Just for display of output, we keep info of combinations in colnames
  apply(combs, 2, function(x) Reduce(`*`, mat[ ,x]))        # multiply the relevant columns
}
N <- 10000
M <- 25
p <- 4
mat <- matrix(runif(N*M),N,M)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fun(mat, p),
  combined(mat, p),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: seconds
#>              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>       fun(mat, p) 3.456853 3.698680 4.067995 4.032647 4.341944 4.869527    10
#>  combined(mat, p) 2.543994 2.738313 2.870446 2.793768 3.090498 3.254232    10
```

Note that the two functions do not yield the same results for `M > 9` since the column ordering is different due to the lexical sorting with `1-10 < 1-2` employed in `fun`. The results would be identical if one inserted the same lexical sorting in `combined`.

Comment: Good job combining both approaches :)

Comment: Very nice!  Bounty awarded.  Thanks to both of you or your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

We create the following function, that takes all the "unique" permutations with chosen `p` and multiply the relevant columns of the matrix :

```
fun <- function(mat,p) {
  mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
  combs <- do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(seq(ncol(mat))),p)) # all combinations including permutations of same values
  combs <- combs[!apply(combs,1,is.unsorted),]              # "unique" permutations only
  rownames(combs) <- apply(combs,1,paste,collapse="-")      # Just for display of output, we keep info of combinations in rownames
  combs <- combs[order(rownames(combs)),]                   # sort to have desired column order on output
  apply(combs,1,function(x) Reduce(`*`,mat[,x]))            # multiply the relevant columns
}
```

**examples**

```
N = 5
M = 3
mat1 = matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   11
# [2,]    2    7   12
# [3,]    3    8   13
# [4,]    4    9   14
# [5,]    5   10   15

M = 4
mat2 = matrix(1:(N*M),N,M)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    2    7   12   17
# [3,]    3    8   13   18
# [4,]    4    9   14   19
# [5,]    5   10   15   20

lapply(2:4,fun,mat=mat1)
# [[1]]
#      1-1 1-2 1-3 2-2 2-3 3-3
# [1,]   1   6  11  36  66 121
# [2,]   4  14  24  49  84 144
# [3,]   9  24  39  64 104 169
# [4,]  16  36  56  81 126 196
# [5,]  25  50  75 100 150 225
# 
# [[2]]
#      1-1-1 1-1-2 1-1-3 1-2-2 1-2-3 1-3-3 2-2-2 2-2-3 2-3-3 3-3-3
# [1,]     1     6    11    36    66   121   216   396   726  1331
# [2,]     8    28    48    98   168   288   343   588  1008  1728
# [3,]    27    72   117   192   312   507   512   832  1352  2197
# [4,]    64   144   224   324   504   784   729  1134  1764  2744
# [5,]   125   250   375   500   750  1125  1000  1500  2250  3375
# 
# [[3]]
#      1-1-1-1 1-1-1-2 1-1-1-3 1-1-2-2 1-1-2-3 1-1-3-3 1-2-2-2 1-2-2-3 1-2-3-3 1-3-3-3 2-2-2-2 2-2-2-3 2-2-3-3 2-3-3-3 3-3-3-3
# [1,]       1       6      11      36      66     121     216     396     726    1331    1296    2376    4356    7986   14641
# [2,]      16      56      96     196     336     576     686    1176    2016    3456    2401    4116    7056   12096   20736
# [3,]      81     216     351     576     936    1521    1536    2496    4056    6591    4096    6656   10816   17576   28561
# [4,]     256     576     896    1296    2016    3136    2916    4536    7056   10976    6561   10206   15876   24696   38416
# [5,]     625    1250    1875    2500    3750    5625    5000    7500   11250   16875   10000   15000   22500   33750   50625

fun(mat2,2)
#      1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4 2-2 2-3 2-4 3-3 3-4 4-4
# [1,]   1   6  11  16  36  66  96 121 176 256
# [2,]   4  14  24  34  49  84 119 144 204 289
# [3,]   9  24  39  54  64 104 144 169 234 324
# [4,]  16  36  56  76  81 126 171 196 266 361
# [5,]  25  50  75 100 100 150 200 225 300 400
```